# iOS, How to know whether a photo is a screenshot taken by user? How to delete photos in Photos?

Tags: ios, analysis, photos

In AppStore(China), an App called Tencent Mobile Manager released a series of functions related to photos, including detecting whether a photo is a screenshot taken by user, deleting photos.

I got screenshots of this app to demonstrate my question here (I added English texts myself for you since the app only shows Chinese):

[This app knows what photos are screenshots and what not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEC5I.jpg)

When you tap Delete Button at the bottom, it shows:

[Asking permission from user to delete photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpBfc.jpg)

As far as I know, Photo APIs (AssetsLibrary, PHPhotoLibrary) in iOS don't give an absolute path of a photo, and iOS SandBox doesn't allow apps to delete user's assets as well, which makes deleting users photos almost impossible. All photos saved in iOS device follows the same naming system: "IMG_001.jpg", which makes it impossible to detect whether a photo is a screenshot from their names.

But apparently, this app implemented both functions. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can check using PHAsset's [`mediaSubtypes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624775-mediasubtypes) property.

```
let types = phAsset.mediaSubtypes /// phAsset is a PHAsset
let isScreenshot = types.contains(.photoScreenshot) /// true if is screenshot
```

Answer (score 1):

For screenshot, its UTI is always a "public.png" and same size as screen (be sure you have multiply [UIScreen scale] on screen bounds width and height), just need to check these 2 metadata, you can easily identify screenshot.

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does UTI refer to?  By the way, I sent several pictures from my mac(all re-sized to 640*1136, iPod Touch 6 in my case) to my iPod to see how they are going to be classified.  Ones I created by capturing my mac screen were classified to the screenshot album, but ones I got from web were not. iOS Photos and Tencent Mobile Manager made the same result.